# How to convert AnyObject type to Int in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, int

I am searching a key in an `Array` of `Dictionarys` and I want to convert the result value into an `Int` value. This is what I tried.

```
if let result = lasrIDArray.flatMap( {$0["\(self.selectedTitle)"]} ).first {      
    print(result)

    if let number = result as? NSNumber {
        let tag = number.integerValue
        let currentScroll = view.viewWithTag(Int(api.selectedCatID)!) as! UIScrollView
        let lastImgVw = currentScroll.viewWithTag(tag) as! UIImageView
        print(lastImgVw.frame.origin.y)
    }
}
```

But `if let number = result as? NSNumber` doesn't work as expected. What is the correct way to convert this value?

Comment: In response are you getting `String` or `Int` please check that?

Comment: var num = Int(result)
if num != nil {
 println("Valid Integer")
}
else {
 println("Not Valid Integer")
}

Comment: Step 1: Cleanly format your code.

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose cannot invoke initializer for type Int with an argument list of type (AnyObject) at  var num = Int(result)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**I don't know your code but this will be helpful for you.**

You can get your **AnyObject** value in this way...

```
let data :AnyObject = "100"
let score = Int(data as! String)! //Force Unwrap optional value it will be dengerious for nil condition.
print(score)
```

---

Or try this way also

```
let hitCount = "100"
let data :AnyObject = hitCount as AnyObject //sometime Xcode will ask value type
let score = Int(data as? String ?? "") ?? 0
print(score)
```

---

### Output -

[image: result]

---

### Swift 3.1 & Swift 4

```
let hitCount = "100"
let data :Any = hitCount //Any type Value passing here 
let score = Int(data as? String ?? "") ?? 0
print(score)
```

---

### Output -

[image]

Comment: So whats the best way for get optional value to non optional. Tell me @dfri ??

Comment: Read [this excellent canonical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32170457/4573247) on the subject. Quote: _"As a general rule, **you should never explicitly force unwrap an optional** with the ! operator"_.

Comment: @dfri In your `Or try this way also`: if the `data:Anyobject`'s value is "abc",could use your method?

Comment: @aircraft I'm sorry, I don't follow. What do you mean by "in _your_ `Or try this way also`"? Note that the thread I linked to is a (great) canonical answer on optionals in general, but I'm not the one who has written it.

Comment: It takes a lot of conversions to get what is asked. Why is that Swift!!..

Answer (score 1):

If your data is decoded from JSON string, it will be decoded as NSNumber or NSString.

You can use this function:

```
func intValueForKey(key: String, inDictionary dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) throws -> Int {
    if let value = dictionary[key]?.integerValue {
        return value
    } else {
        throw NSError(domain: "Invalid key", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have given example to convert Anyobject to Int and String

```
var idInt : Int = 0
if let ids: AnyObject = responseDict["id"] {
    if let idsInt = ids as? Int{
        idInt  = idsInt
        print(idInt)
    }
}


var nameString : String = ""
    if let name: AnyObject = responseDict["name"] {
        if let nameStr = name as? String{
            nameString  = nameStr
            print(nameString)
        }
    }
```