# Enum of structs in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, enums, rawrepresentable

I am trying to create an enum of a struct that I would like to initialize:

```
struct CustomStruct {
    var variable1: String
    var variable2: AnyClass
    var variable3: Int

    init (variable1: String, variable2: AnyClass, variable3: Int) {
        self.variable1 = variable1
        self.variable2 = variable2
        self.variable3 = variable3
    }
}

enum AllStructs: CustomStruct {
    case getData
    case addNewData

    func getAPI() -> CustomStruct {
        switch self {
            case getData:
                return CustomStruct(variable1:"data1", variable2: SomeObject.class, variable3: POST)

            case addNewData:
                // Same to same

            default:
                return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Type AllStructs does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'

I am assuming that enums cannot be used this way. We must use primitives.

Comment: You don't have any property named `apiUrl`, nor `responseType`, nor `httpType`. Please first check the errors of your code in playground and then edit your question. Your `init` method also has two `variable3`, I wanted to make an edit, but it's better you do it yourself so you know what you did wrong

Comment: what is `MNOX_MAPPINGS` what are you trying to do in your `getAPI` func?

Comment: sorry the question was badly formed.. have made corrections..

Comment: please let me know what more can be done to correct my question..

Comment: @Siddharth as I mentioned in my answer, I think you should take care of the naming conventions...

Comment: Swift convention is to use UpperCamelCase for type names, such as for structs, enums and classes. Stick to it.

Comment: where can i find these conventions.. point to one.. i'll make sure i learn them now. thanks

Answer (score 23):

It should be:

```
struct CustomStruct {
    var apiUrl: String
    var responseType: AnyObject
    var httpType: Int

    init (variable1: String, variable2: AnyObject, variable3: Int) {
        self.apiUrl = variable1
        self.responseType = variable2
        self.httpType = variable3
    }
}

enum MyEnum {
    case getData
    case addNewData

    func getAPI() -> CustomStruct {
        switch self {
        case .getData:
            return CustomStruct(variable1: "URL_TO_GET_DATA", variable2: 11 as AnyObject, variable3: 101)
        case .addNewData:
            return CustomStruct(variable1: "URL_TO_ADD_NEW_DATA", variable2: 12 as AnyObject, variable3: 102)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let data = MyEnum.getData
let myObject = data.getAPI()

// this should logs: "URL_TO_GET_DATA 11 101"
print(myObject.apiUrl, myObject.responseType, myObject.httpType)
```

Note that upon Naming Conventions, struct should named as `CustomStruct` and enum named as `MyEnum`.

In fact, I'm not pretty sure of the need of letting `CustomStruct` to be the parent of `MyEnum` to achieve what are you trying to; As mentioned above in the snippets, you can return an instance of the struct based on what is the value of the referred enum.

Comment: What do you mean by `11 as AnyObject`, can you point me to a doc reference to read up about this syntax

Comment: @Siddharth ya for sure, [AnyObject Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyobject) and [AnyClass Type Alias](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyclass).

Comment: @Siddharth your might also want to check this [What is AnyObject?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-anyobject) and [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369544/how-to-convert-anyobject-type-to-int-in-swift). Hope this helped :)

Answer (score 14):

I'm not commenting on the choice to use an enum here, but just explaining why you got that error and *how to declare an enum that has a custom object as parent*.

The error shows you the problem, `CustomStruct` must implement [`RawRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rawrepresentable) to be used as base class of that enum.

Here is a simplified example that shows you what you need to do:

```
struct CustomStruct : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, Equatable {
    var rawValue: Int = 0

    init(integerLiteral value: Int){
        self.rawValue = value
    }

    static func == (lhs: CustomStruct, rhs: CustomStruct) -> Bool {
        return
            lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
    }
}


enum AllStructs: CustomStruct {
    case ONE = 1
    case TWO = 2
}
```

A few important things that we can see in this snippet:

1. The cases like ONE and TWO **must** be representable with a Swift *literal*, check [this Swift 2 post](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/) for a list of available literals (int,string,array,dictionary,etc...). But please note that in Swift 3, the *LiteralConvertible* protocols are now called *ExpressibleByXLiteral* after the Big Swift Rename.
2. The requirement to implement `RawRepresentable` is covered implementing one of the Expressible protocols (`init?(rawValue:)` will leverage the initializer we wrote to support literals).
3. Enums **must** also be *Equatable* , so you'll have to implement the equality operator for your `CustomStruct` base type.

Comment: Actually `CUSTOM_STRUCT` doesn't need to conform to `RawRepresentable` – only a suitable `ExpressibleByXLiteral` protocol and `Equatable`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html):

> If a value (known as a “raw” value) is *provided* for each enumeration case, the value can be a string, a character, or a value of any integer or floating-point type.

So yes, you cannot set a struct type to be enum's raw value.

In your case I would suggest using `string` as the enum raw value and some dictionary mapping these strings to `CUSTOM_STRUCT` type.

Comment: Note that the bit of documentation you quote is slightly misleading – you can have a raw value of a type that's representable by a string, character, integer or floating point *literal* (and you can add this behaviour to your own types). Although I don't see how OP could effectively do this for his `CUSTOM_STRUCT`, or even why he'd want to do this in the first place.

Comment: @Hamish Probably only by parsing a string literal. Which would be a terrible solution.

Comment: @Sulthan Yeah – that's what I meant by "effectively" :) In any case, it doesn't look like OP wants `ALL_STRUCTS` to have a raw value of type `CUSTOM_STRUCT` – he just wants a method.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try conforming to RawRepresentable like the error is asking?

Using JSON representation should work for variable1 and variable3. Some extra work may be required for variable2.

```
struct CustomStruct: RawRepresentable {
    var variable1: String
    var variable2: AnyClass
    var variable3: Int
    init?(rawValue: String) {
        guard let data = rawValue.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
            return nil
        }
        self.variable1 = (json["variable1"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.variable2 = (json["variable2"] as? AnyClass) ?? AnyClass()
        self.variable3 = (json["variable3"] as? Int) ?? 0
    }
    var rawValue: String {
        let json = ["variable1": self.variable1,
                    "variable2": self.variable2,
                    "variable3": self.variable3
                    ]
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []) else {
            return ""
        }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this answer too and get back

Answer (score 2):

A bit late on the party but maybe useful for someone else. I would consider to simply use computed variables instead of a struct.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case getData
    case addNewData

    var variable1: String {
        switch self {
            case .getData: return "data1"
            case .addNewData: return "data2"
        }
    }
    
    var variable2: Int {
        switch self {
            case .getData: return 1
            case .addNewData: return 2
        }
    }
    
    // ....
}
```

Usage:

```
let data = MyEnum.getData

print (data.variable1) // "data1"
```